# Read a JSON file and select node like in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json

I need to read a JSON config file like the example below and change some of its values with a querying structure like in Pandas.

Ex:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5d1f5d0289725ba2c32695ac",
    "index": 0,
    "guid": "d1a8c2e2-1011-4db2-97a8-b68777c2d18b",
    "isActive": false,
    "name": {
      "first": "Barnett",
      "last": "Obrien"
    },
    "latitude": "-76.327744",
    "longitude": "-131.003501",
    "friends": [
      {
        "friend_id": 0,
        "name": "Burnett Burke"
      },
      {
        "friend_id": 1,
        "name": "Lawrence Hunt"
      },
      {
        "friend_id": 2,
        "name": "Nola Benjamin"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "5d1f5d023ef4523b5e326ae2",
    "index": 1,
    "guid": "6b0ad8a7-2b10-4892-9b91-fc7445038aca",
    "isActive": true,
    "name": {
      "first": "Valerie",
      "last": "Preston"
    },
    "latitude": "27.995886",
    "longitude": "170.930419",
    "friends": [
      {
        "friend_id": 0,
        "name": "Gretchen Hobbs"
      },
      {
        "friend_id": 1,
        "name": "Irene Fox"
      },
      {
        "friend_id": 2,
        "name": "Porter King"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Then I wanted to change the value for the `friend_id == 1` and object with `guid == 6b0ad8a7-2b10-4892-9b91-fc7445038aca` from `Irene Fox` to something else.

With Pandas I can have something like this:

```
valerie = dataframe['guid'] == '6b0ad8a7-2b10-4892-9b91-fc7445038aca'
friend1 = dataframe['friend_1'] == 1

dataframe[valerie & friend1]['name'] = 'Karen Smith'
```

How can I achieve this without having to add Pandas dependency?

Comment: what\s your expected resulting structure and its type? Post the expected result

Comment: After updating the value like this `dataframe[valerie & friend1]['name'] = 'Karen Smith'`, I need to save the JSON file back in the same structure as before. The internal data structure in my script may be a dictionary or tuple to achieve the querying capability.

Answer (score 0):

With simple loop:

```
import json
import sys

data = json.load(open('input.json'))
for d in data:
    if d["guid"] == "6b0ad8a7-2b10-4892-9b91-fc7445038aca":
        for f in d["friends"]:
            if f["friend_id"] == 1:
                f["name"] = "Karen Smith"
                # break <- uncomment if only one match is implied

# replace sys.stdout with output file pointer
json.dump(data, sys.stdout, indent=4)
```

you may also `break` the outer `for` loop if items/dicts have unique *guids*.

---

The output (for demonstration):

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5d1f5d0289725ba2c32695ac",
        "index": 0,
        "guid": "d1a8c2e2-1011-4db2-97a8-b68777c2d18b",
        "isActive": false,
        "name": {
            "first": "Barnett",
            "last": "Obrien"
        },
        "latitude": "-76.327744",
        "longitude": "-131.003501",
        "friends": [
            {
                "friend_id": 0,
                "name": "Burnett Burke"
            },
            {
                "friend_id": 1,
                "name": "Lawrence Hunt"
            },
            {
                "friend_id": 2,
                "name": "Nola Benjamin"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "5d1f5d023ef4523b5e326ae2",
        "index": 1,
        "guid": "6b0ad8a7-2b10-4892-9b91-fc7445038aca",
        "isActive": true,
        "name": {
            "first": "Valerie",
            "last": "Preston"
        },
        "latitude": "27.995886",
        "longitude": "170.930419",
        "friends": [
            {
                "friend_id": 0,
                "name": "Gretchen Hobbs"
            },
            {
                "friend_id": 1,
                "name": "Karen Smith"
            },
            {
                "friend_id": 2,
                "name": "Porter King"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, however this won't give the same capability as Pandas dataframe querying. Using the guid and friend_id were just an example. The developer using this structure may (and will) have different needs (querying for a single key, instead of two in my example and so on.

Comment: @JulianoNunesSilvaOliveira, you did write *without having to add Pandas dependency*. You said "may have different needs" - describe the logic of those needs to realize a scale of potential functional approach. Because the current approach covers your initial conditions/requirements

Comment: The user can search for a node using any keys, for example: `dataframe['latitude'] < 27`, `dataframe[dataframe['friend_1'] == 2 & dataframe['index'] == 1]`. I mean, the order of the filters are not fixed, neither the key names.

Comment: @JulianoNunesSilvaOliveira, it would become even more complicated if filtering on nested list and arbitrary keys of dicts within nested lists. So for such filtering you need to know the structure beforehand - that's the precondition

Comment: I get that, so let's suppose I'm working on a simple list instead of a nested one (maybe I can transform it on memory, but I can think about it latter). The question in this case would be how filtering can be achieved using such expressions such as the ones I've posted before.